# Duda sobre la metodología de BEM

Tags: html, css, bem

Estoy estudiando la metodología de BEM y me surgió una duda que es básicamente cómo identificar los Bloques cuando tengo varios elementos anidados. Siguiendo el siguiente código:

```
<div>
    <main>
        <article>
            <h2>Viajar a Londres</h2>
            <img src="img/imagen_1.jpg" alt="visitar londres">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#" class="boton">Leer más</a>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h2>Puente de la Torre</h2>
            <img src="img/imagen_2.jpg" alt="puente de la torre">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#" class="boton">Leer más</a>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h2>Metro de Londres</h2>
            <img src="img/imagen_3.jpg" alt="metro de londres">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#" class="boton">Leer más</a>
        </article>
    </main>

    <aside>
        <h2>Otros posts</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Entrada 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Entrada 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Entrada 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Entrada 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Entrada 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</div> <!--contenido-->
```

Como puedo identificar los bloques? Es el `div`,`main`, `article`, o `aside`?

A simple vista me parecería que los bloques serían cada uno de los `article` y el `aside`, y lo que esta dentro de ellos sus respectivos elementos, pero no se si esté bien.

Comment: Hola, como ya sabes el código va como texto por favor

Comment: Ahí lo cambié, se me pasó

Comment: si revisas este enlace seguro se solventan todas tus dudas: https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#block

Answer (score 0):

Aun tengo muchas dudas sobre como utilizar la metodología BEM ya que hay ciertos problemas que un no he encontrado solución, por lo que he entendido BEM utiliza clases para darle estilos a todos los elementos en CSS viéndolos como bloques para ser reutilizados en cado de que se necesite. Sin embargo a uno como novato le vienen ciertas dudas con respecto a su forma de usar, por ejemplo; el mantener el nombre en la relación, elemento padre-hijo-nieto-etc. ya que el nombre es muy largo, queda muy extenso el código y difícil de leer, por lo que una posible solución a esto sea utilizar un nombre en relación a lo que se esta poniendo de contenido en la etiqueta para no poner ese nombre tan largo, como por ejemplo ponerle `post__link` en ves de `post__list__item__link` o un mejor ejemplo; `article__title` en vez de `article__h2`. En su defecto limitar la cantidad de nombres relacionados cortando hasta cierto punto podría funcionar, como por ejemplo; `article__main` en vez de `article__main__block`.

También se recomienda poner `ts-funcionalidad` por ejemplo; `ts-click`, para cuando vas a necesitar meterle alguna funcionalidad con JavaScript.

```
<div class="block">
    <main class="main__block">
        <article class="article__main">
            <h2 class="article__title">Viajar a Londres</h2>
            <img src="img/imagen_1.jpg" alt="visitar londres" class="article__img">
            <p class="article__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p class="article__text">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#" class="article__link boton">Leer más</a>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h2 class="article__title">Puente de la Torre</h2>
            <img src="img/imagen_2.jpg" alt="puente de la torre" class="article__img">
            <p class="article__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p class="article__text">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#" class="article__link boton">Leer más</a>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h2 class="article__title">Metro de Londres</h2>
            <img src="img/imagen_3.jpg" alt="metro de londres" class="article__img">
            <p class="article__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p class="article__text">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#" class="article__img">Leer más</a>
        </article>
    </main>

    <aside class="main__aside">
        <h2 class="aside__post">Otros posts</h2>
        <ul class="post__list">
          <li class="post__list__item"><a class="post__link" href="#">Entrada 1</a></li>
          <li class="post__list__item"><a class="post__link" href="#">Entrada 2</a></li>
          <li class="post__list__item"><a class="post__link" href="#">Entrada 3</a></li>
          <li class="post__list__item"><a class="post__link" href="#">Entrada 4</a></li>
          <li class="post__list__item"><a class="post__link" href="#">Entrada 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</div> <!--contenido-->
```